# How can I make only one random space invader shoot?

Tags: java, processing

I have been working on making my own version of space invaders, I literally have everything working besides allowing my aliens to shoot, the problem is now I have a 2D array of aliens (15 by 3) that I want to have shoot a missile, each time it shoots I want it to come from a random alien, not all at once.

Currently I have the missiles shooting at random intervals but all the aliens shoot at once making it near impossible to play the game.

Here is a snippet of my code from where I have the aliens being drawn and also them shooting:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) { //Adds aliens on the screen (15 by 3)
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    if (alien[i][j] != null) {
      alien[i][j].updateAlien();
      if (alien[i][j].edgeDetection() == true) { //If the edge is hit 
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
          for (int l = 0; l < 15; l++) {
            if (alien[l][k] != null) {
              alien[l][k].deltaX = - alien[l][k].deltaX; //the aliens move the opposite direction
              alien[l][k].y = alien[l][k].y + 25; //the aliens move down a little
            }
          }
        }
      }
      for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 15; l++) {
          if (alien[l][k] != null) {
            if (alienMissileCounter % 75 == 0) { //If the random int is divisible by 75 then the Aliens shoot a missile
              missileAlien.add(new MissileAlien(alien[l][k].x, alien[l][k].y, 10));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I added the [l][k] bit on my missile thinking only one would shoot but that did the opposite.

Here is also the for loop used to add the number of missiles:

```
    for (int m = missileAlien.size()-1; m >= 0; m--) { //This adds one missile each time
  MissileAlien missilesalien = missileAlien.get(m); //This gets the number of missile i.e. 1
  missilesalien.updateMissile(); //This draws and moves the missile

  if (missilesalien.hitDefender(player) == true) { //If the defender is hit it loses a life
    missileAlien.remove(m);
    lives -= 1;
  }
}
```

If you need me to paste any other code you think might help I will be more than happy to do so, it isn't much of a big deal as I have the rest of the game complete so if it isn't solvable then don't worry.

UPDATE: After comments were made here is what my code looks like now:

```
    alienMissileCounter = int(random(0, 100));


//Adds Aliens
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) { //Adds aliens on the screen (15 by 3)
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    if (alien[i][j] != null) {
      alien[i][j].updateAlien();
      if (alien[i][j].edgeDetection() == true) { //If the edge is hit 
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
          for (int l = 0; l < 15; l++) {
            if (alien[l][k] != null) {
              alien[l][k].deltaX = - alien[l][k].deltaX; //the aliens move the opposite direction
              alien[l][k].y = alien[l][k].y + 25; //the aliens move down a little
            }
          }
        }
      }
      for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 15; l++) {
          if (alien[l][k] != null) {
            if (alienMissileCounter == 75) { //If the random int is divisible by 75 then the Aliens shoot a missile
              alienMissileCounter = 0;
              missileAlien.add(new MissileAlien(alien[l][k].x, alien[l][k].y, 10));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What code are you using to generate `alienMissileCounter ` counter and where is it called? If you're not regenerating it everytime you go go round the loop then for all aliens it's going to the same value. So all aliens get missiles, or none do.

Comment: The problem is your `alienMissleEncounter % 75`.  Run it through a calculator and every 3rd one == 0, every other one == 0.000000000025 or 0.000000000050.  You mean to generate a random number between 0 and 74.  So `new Random().nextInt(75)`.  Look up Java Random

Comment: do you initialize the aliens in setup()?

Comment: @Cr1xus yes I do

Comment: @jnbbender the missilecounter is a random number, so it shoots at random intervals but i need to get it so it randomly selects an invader to shoot from each time

Comment: So my statement still holds.  In a calculator type, `872634892364.257 % 75` see what you get or `2.1 % 75` or `19938037687623467523476 % 75`

Comment: @jnbbender it is a random number between 0,100 so the only time it will shoot is when it equals 75, granted I could have it so it says == instead of % == 0 but I originally had multiple numbers and didn't change it

Comment: So, `67 % 75 = 0.000000000025` (i.e. 0) shot fired, `30 % 75 = 0` (i.e. 0) shot fired, `89 % 75 = 0.000000000050` (i.e. 0) shot fired, `90 % 75 = 0` shot fired.

Comment: @jnbbender I have changed it now so it says when alienMissileCounter is equal to 75 if it makes it any better, that still doesn't change the fact all the aliens still shoot a missile instead of e.g. the 5th one on the top row then the 7th one on the 3rd etc

Comment: You have to `break` after you `.add(new MissleAlien())`.  Since the one time when you are ready to fire you are still looping through ALL of your aliens and your if condition still holds true.  More than `break`, get out of that outer loop.

Comment: @jnbbender Okay I added break; after it adds a new missile but now it shoots all the missile from the same spot.

Comment: Have you tried putting a print statement in just before the if statement to see what the random number actually is each time? I suspect it's not being reset so it's always true.

Comment: @Matt Watson I made it so it resets each time once it hits 75 so it only shoots once now but I need it so it randomly changes from invader to invader that's literally the last thing I want from the game

Comment: @Ryan reset the number every time you go round the loop - I.e on the line before you do the % 75 comparison

Comment: @Matt Watson yes I have done that, still doesn't work fully

Comment: @Ryan could you update the code sample to show exactly what you're doing? I can't see the number being reset in there.

Comment: @Matt Watson, I've updated the code in the post, if that helps

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate two randoms:

```
int row = (int) random(numRows);
int col = (int) random(numCols);
```

But then you need to check if that spot is `null`, and try again - repeatedly until `row`, `col` isn't `null`.  But then there's a danger of getting into an infinite loop if there are NO aliens in the 2d array - or it takes 100 tries to find a non-`null` alien (e.g. there are only two left out of 45 spots).

If you aren't totally married to your 2d array data structure, I would recommend using one of the Java collection types - maybe an ArrayList.  The biggest selling point is that they are *dynamic* arrays.

You just `.add()` all your aliens up front, and `.remove()` them when they're hit (instead of setting that spot to `null`).  Your ArrayList will contain exactly the number of aliens visible on-screen.  Then picking a random one is super easy:

```
// Assuming:
//  your alien class is Alien
//  your list is created like:
ArrayList<Alien> aliens = new ArrayList<Alien>();
//  aliens are added at some point, like:
aliens.add( new Alien() );

// in your loop that wants to drop a missile:
if ( aliens.size() > 0 ) {
  int randomIndex = (int) random( aliens.size() );
  Alien theAlien = aliens.get( randomIndex );
  // drop a missile from `alien`
}
```

By the way, your draw loop would be a lot simpler, too:

```
boolean hitEdge = false;
for ( Alien alien : aliens ) {
  alien.updateAlien();
  hitEdge = hitEdge || alien.edgeDetection();
}
if ( hitEdge ) {
  for ( Alien alien : aliens ) {
    // do your bounced-off-the-edge stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha! I got it! I changed your method slightly by acquiring a random number and comparing it to the x coordinate of my alien so it looks like they all shoot randomly

Answer (score 0):

Why not use builtin java random number generator to activate the invader with random index value. 
If you like coding then try generating the pseudo-random numbers by using any random number generating algorithms like **linear consequential method** or **Middle square method**. These are very simple algorithms based on short mathematical formula.

Comment: I am using a random number generator so the missiles shoot at random times but I don't know about making it so the missile comes from a different alien each time

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < 15; l++) {
        if (alien[l][k] != null) {
            if (alienMissileCounter == 75) { //If the random int is divisible by 75 then the Aliens shoot a missile
            //This area of code will only be reached if the initial value of 
            //alienMissileCounter is equal to 75 initially. If it is not, then no alien 
            //will have any missile. Also once this area is reached for the first time, 
            //only the first alien will shoot a missile and no subsequent alien can 
            //shoot a missile
                alienMissileCounter = 0;
                missileAlien.add(new MissileAlien(alien[l][k].x, alien[l][k].y, 10));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your code above, you are going over the whole area (15*3) and updating the missile based on whether an alien is present there or not. So every time you are updating your game for every alien present in the area. So you need to generate the random number inside the loop and not before like you have done. I have also added some comments in the code itself

You should use something like this in your code:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < 15; l++) {
        if (alien[l][k] != null) {
            alienMissileCounter = int(random(0, 100)); 
            //Every time an alien is detected, a new random number is 
            //generated. Now if it's equal to 75 as you want, this alien 
            //will shoot a missile otherwise not
            if (alienMissileCounter == 75) { //If the random int is divisible by 75 then the Aliens shoot a missile
                alienMissileCounter = 0;
                missileAlien.add(new MissileAlien(alien[l][k].x, alien[l][k].y, 10));
            }
        }
    }
}
```